# Laravel sorting by sum of remote column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

So I have a table film that has various information in it, picture, title, director, ID, etc. I also have a separate table called votes. The votes table has id, filmId, value. Default value is 1, but this can change depending on who votes (weighted votes) so I am trying to call a eloquent query that will get films in order of their value sum. Based on another stackoverflow question I have come up with this.

```
    $films = Film::join('votes', 'films.id', '=', 'votes.filmId')->orderBy(DB::raw('sum(\'votes.value\')'), 'DESC')->groupby('votes.filmId')->get();
```

This does not work as intended. Basically I want to go to the votes table, grab all the votes that correspond to a film id and sum up the value column and order by that. Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: If it doesn't work as intended, then what is expected result and how is it different to what you get?

Comment: What is expected is I want my list of films, in order based on the sum of the votes with that film ID. What happens is a seemingly random order of films.

Comment: This is what the query does. However by using `get()` you do `select *` and I'm sure you have overlapping fields in these 2 tables, so you get unexpected results. Use `select('films.*', DB::raw('sum(votes.value) as votes'))` to get what you want.